# Scrolling lags (blinks) with UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have implemented an Appstore/Netflix like UI where there is a UITableView and inside each (custom) cell there is a UICollectionView scrolling horizontally.

Each UITableView cell functions as the delegate and data source for its collectionView. The data is being held by a variable inside the tableView cell that's being set during the tableView's cellForRow call.

Upon setting the new variable, didSet performs some actions and calls collectionView.ReloadData() in order for the collectionView to reflect the current data. This causes lags when scrolling, probably because of each collectionView.ReloadData() call.

The data is a struct with some metadata and the content itself in an array.

cellForRow:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: contentTableCellId, for: indexPath) as! ContentTableCell
    cell.contentItem = contentItems[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

and inside ContentTableCell:

```
    var contentItem: ContentItem!{
    didSet{
        ... //some simple text label actions.
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe share some code from your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method?

Comment: Sure, added it to the main question.

Comment: You may be trying to do too much on the main thread. This would cause the UI to stutter. Try doing whatever non-UI related things you can on a background thread and see if that helps.

Comment: I have a doubt that `didSet` is called multiple times for the same cell instead of being called once, hence `reloadData` will be called multiple times and probably causes the performance issues. I would suggest changing the way of handling the collection view operations. I loved how Ash Furrow is doing that in [his post](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift). Maybe it would be helpful for you.

Comment: You are correct, that is exactly the problem. I'm trying to think my way around it. I actually started building this following Ash's post. His use of generics for the delegate and data source results in the same refresh of the collection view.